# json parsing & is getting as &amp; - iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, json

After parsing Json data, in the parsing result Iam getting & as &amp;. Why this is happening?
Is there any solution for getting & only? How to do this?

Comment: where you show this parsing string in TextView or Webview..?

Comment: contact to your webservice provider?

Answer (score 0):

First of the you receive the string from  the response then you remove the "&" from the string for that code is following.

```
 NSString *string = @"Your Response";
 totalString = [totalString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"$"" withString:@""];
```

Then now convert the string to json form you use the [jsonkit library](https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit)

```
NSDictionary *deserializedData = [jsonString objectFromJSONString];
```

May This help to you.

Comment: I want that & symbol and need to avoid the &amp;

Comment: you just replace that character and check it out